# Не могу задать height 100%

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть `div`, в нем есть еще один `div`, в этом `div` есть 2 `div`. Не могу указать значение `height:100%` для второго `div` (родительского двух дочерних `div`). В чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:100%;height:100%;">
  
  <div style="border-radius: 5px;width:25%;height:100%;margin-right:10px;display:block;display:inline-block;">
  <div style="height:60%;background:#000;border-radius: 5px;display:inline-block;width:100%;margin-bottom:8px;">
  </div>
  <div style="height:38%;background:#000;border-radius: 5px;display:inline-block;width:100%;">
  <input type="button" value="Предчек" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">
  <input type="button" value="Чек" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">
  <input type="button" value="Удалить заказ" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">

  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию у `body` высота **0**. А у тебя  высота в процентах, процент от родителя берется...

Кстати, а у `html` ***`8px`*** по умолчанию

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:100%;height:100%;">

  <div style="border-radius: 5px;width:25%;height:100%;margin-right:10px;display:block;display:inline-block;">
    <div style="height:60%;background:#000;border-radius: 5px;display:inline-block;width:100%;margin-bottom:8px;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:38%;background:#000;border-radius: 5px;display:inline-block;width:100%;">
      <input type="button" value="Предчек" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">
      <input type="button" value="Чек" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">
      <input type="button" value="Удалить заказ" style="width: 90%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 20px;border: 2px solid #edc951;height: 40px;    background: #fff;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 5px;">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Наглядный пример

```js
console.log('Высота body -- ', getComputedStyle(document.body)['height']);
console.log('Высота html -- ', getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)['height']);
```